# Sync Sqlite database with iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, icloud

I have an application which is already on app store and it use Sqlite Database. Now i want to make another version, which include iCloud sync, now ,the question is ,IS there any tutorial or third party code   of syncing sqlite database with iCloud ,as i searched a lot but didn't get any useable answer??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as I know, standalone sqlite syncing with iCloud is highly unreliable. Apple allows syncing of sqlite data with iCloud only when core data is used with sqlite db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLite and iCloud do not mix well. Although it's possible to use the iCloud file APIs to put a SQLite file in iCloud, doing so is almost guaranteed to corrupt the file. SQLite wasn't designed with this kind of use in mind, and between external journal files, uncommitted transactions, etc, it's not even a question of whether the file gets corrupted, only of when (and the answer is "very soon").

Although Core Data can use both SQLite files and iCloud, it doesn't sync the SQLite file. Instead it has a scheme that uses transaction logs to send changes back and forth.

If you want to use your existing data with iCloud, you'll probably have to do something similar. I don't know of any good reference implementations. Basically, you'll need to export your data to some other format, and detect and import changes from other devices.

Comment: Apple has done WWDC sessions on this, both this year and last year. The videos are available to registered developers. There might be other videos, but those are the ones I know.